# Improve 3D plot visualization in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

im working in a cascade plot of Fft spectrum (large data, more than 2 million samples). I made an plot_wireframe with matplot lib, the line code is:

```
x=df_fftc['freq']
y=np.arange(len(Z))
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z,rstride=1,cstride=len(x), lw=.5)
```

where:

```
X is the freq range of the Fft 
Y is the plot number axis
Z is the 2D array with Fft data
```

the plot looks like:
[image]

which is quite a mess, you cant see every plot in a nice way, also i cant understand what rstride and cstride do to the plot. Anyone, any idea? maybe change the color of every line plot and add a bit of transparency (how can you do that).
Greets :)

EDIT: adding transparency (0.5) looks a little better:

```
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=len(x), lw=.5,alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

adding rainbow color seems to be the hard part x)

Comment: transparency is set with `alpha=...`

Comment: If you loop over the Y values and plot on the same figure, you should see individual colors